# Why I am getting this error that 'a' is not in list? How can I make this work to print indices of duplicate elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys

j=['a','b','c','a']

l=None

leng=len(j)

try:

    l = j.index('a')

except ValueError:

    print("List does not contain value")

print("Index of first occurence is: " )

print(l)

print("Index/Indices of duplicate elements are:" )

if l<=0:
  
     while l<leng:

        l+= 1

        l=j.index('a',l,leng)

        print(l)
```

Comment: Because at some point in your while loop, you iterate when `l` is 3 which means you start looking for `a` from index 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Look at the stack trace of the exception
2. Use the debugger, to execute one command at a time, and see where it
   fails

We can see

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/code/EPMD/Kodex/Applications/EPMD-Software/BaseProcess/sss.py", line 28, in <module>
    l = j.index('a', l, leng)
ValueError: 'a' is not in list
```

You are looking for `'a'` in a list that doesn't contain it!

working code:

```
j = [ 'a', 'b',  'c', 'a']

l = None

leng = len(j)

try:

    l = j.index('a')

except ValueError:

    print("List does not contain value")

print("Index of first occurence is: ")

print(l)

print("Index/Indices of duplicate elements are:")

while l < leng:
    if j[l] == "a":
        print(l)
    l += 1
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your time. I was not expecting a response this soon.